# Assign static IP to network interface

Tags: networking, network-manager

I'm following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/isc-dhcp-server) for setting up a DHCP server. The guide says to assign for static ip to eth0 interface using NetworkManager. I've had a look at the [NetworkManager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager) page, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: are using the graphical Network Manager?

Comment: @MarkYisri no, nmcli

Comment: Is this configuration going to be permanent? If so - why not do it without network manager, directly in the /etc/network/interfaces ? I think the posted guide serves more GUI oriented solutions...

Comment: Can you also add your version of Ubuntu as there are some minor changes in the nmcli syntax AFAIR... Basically [Example 9](https://people.freedesktop.org/~lkundrak/nm-docs/nmcli-examples.html) will give a good point how to do it. But I suggest do it the other way using [/etc/network/interfaces](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic)

Comment: I second @RostislavKandilarov suggestion. Since you are setting up a DHCP server, its IP address will be static and stable. Defining it in `/etc/network/interfaces` then is a logical and simple option. NetworkManager picks up interfaces defined in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: I also agree with @RostislavKandilarov on this. Just use the GUI.

Comment: Thanks guys. Looks like modifying /etc/network/interfaces directly is what I need.